# Best practices to handle server side validation/exception in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I always used to fetch HTTP response with a TypeScript object.

```js
validateTokenHttp(token: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(`${environment.api}/auth/verifyToken/${token}`);
}
```

Sometimes it will return `User` object or `Account Not Verified` or `Account Not Valid` or `Account is __some resonse__`.

The question is what is the best practice to handle it?

The possibilities I've considered are:

1. Send response with status code `401` or others,

   ```js
   this.validateTokenHttp(token)
       .subscribe(
         (user) => {
             // do success operation
         },
         (error) => {
            if(error.status == 401){
                console.log(error.error); // do the exception
            }
         }
       );
   ```

   - Response

     ```js
     // Status Code: 401
     {message: "Account Not Verified"}
     ```

   **NOTE:** In this case we say status code `401`, Actually we can have multiple different validation in server which is not suits to status code `401`.
2. Send validation errors inside the HTTP response with status code `200`

   ```js
   validateTokenHttp(token: string): Observable<any> {
       return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.api}/auth/verifyToken/${token}`);
   }

   getUser(){
       this.validateTokenHttp(token)
       .subscribe(data=>{
           if(data.success == true){
           //do success operation
           }
           else{
           //do the exception operation
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   - Response 1

     ```js
     //Status Code: 200
     {success: true, data: "--User details JSON object"}
     ```
   - Response 2

     ```js
     //Status Code: 200
     {success: false, message: "Account Not Verified"}
     ```

But if we go for solution 2, need to change the return type `validateTokenHttp(token: string): Observable<User>` to `validateTokenHttp(token: string): Observable<any>`. I think using `<any>` object might not be good one.

Is there any way to predict two objects? `Observable<User || CustomErrorObject>`

Is there any way to ensure we got `User` object?

Can anybody tell me which is the best practice to handle these kind of server validations/responses?

Comment: Yes, you can have a union type `Observable<User | CustomErrorObject>`; as it looks like you have `success` being true or false you can discriminate the union as shown in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: Well it's up to you, this question is very opinion based. It also depends on what do you do when there is an error, is it likely to happen, who else coonsume your API etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is not 1 good answer to this, but I'll try to give my perspective for it.

**I would always prefer option 1.**

First - it makes much sense to return 401 when the user is unauthorized. You prefer to build API that others can understand and use, so standards are important for me.

Second - I always prefer to handle HTTP errors within the observable with the `catchError` operator. The main reason is, errors can break your stream chain. Handling the error with `catchError` will keep you observable alive and will let you decide what the stream should return.

Besides, you can always return:
`Observable<User | ErrorObject>`

Comment: Can you share the sample code or gist code for second?

Comment: `httpClient.get<User>(...).pipe(catchError((error) => return of(ErrorObject)))`